# How to query mongo db collection based on reference in document array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have a project that pairs zip codes with industries and searches these terms together.

I have 2 collections. 1 collection is for the industries and the other collection is for the zip codes.

Here are the mongoose schemas.

```
const ZipSchema = new Schema({
    zip: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
})

const IndexedSchema = new Schema({
    zip: {type:ObjectId, required: true, default: "pending"},
    last_indexed: {type:Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
})
const IndustrySchema = new Schema({
    zips_indexed: [IndexedSchema],
    industry_name: {type:String, required: true, unique: true},
})
```

Basically what has to happen is I want to be able to pair up search queries. For example
"landscaper 11111" and then when my other function searches it will be added to the "zips_indexed" for that specific industry. (in order to prevent duplicate queries)

What I am trying to figure out is the best way to get x amount of search terms (i.e "landscaper 11111") without duplicates.

My idea on how I would do this would be to loop through the industries. Let say we have these industries
[
"landscaper"
"dentist"
"mechanic"
]

then loop through the zip codes and for each industry but with a limit because I don't want to loop through thousands of zip codes and then return both the industry document and the zip document

Here is what the inputs and outputs would look like in psuedo code

```
let industries = [
 {
  industry: "landscaper"
  zips_indexed: ["11111","11112"]
 }
 {
  industry: "dentist"
  zips_indexed: ["11114"]
 }
 {
  industry: "mechanic"
  zips_indexed: []
 }
]

let zips = [
 "11111",
 "11112",
 "11113",
 "11114",
]
//These would be mongoose collections but for simplicity I am representing them as js arrays and json objects

function getSearchPairs(limit){
  for(industry in industries){
    //get zip codes
    // Check if zipcode is in the "zip_indexed" array for current industry
    if(zip is in zips_indexed){
      //go to next zip code
    }else{
      //add to array that this function will return
    }
    //Continue making pairs until the limit is hit or we run out of pairs to make
  }
}
```

```
getSearchPairs(2) // would return something like this
[
 {
   industry: Dentist (industry ObjectID)
   zip: 11111 (zip objectID)
  },
 {
   industry: Dentist (industry ObjectID)
   zip: 11112 (zip objectID)
  }
 {
   industry: Landscaper (industry ObjectID)
   zip: 11113 (zip objectID)
  }
 {
   industry: Landscaper (industry ObjectID)
   zip: 11114 (zip objectID)
  }
 {
   industry: Mechanic (industry ObjectID)
   zip: 11111 (zip objectID)
  },
 {
   industry: Mechanic (industry ObjectID)
   zip: 11112 (zip objectID)
  }
]
```

This is my thought process there might be a much better way but I am fairly new to mongoose and mongodb.

Comment: Just thought that It might be best if its the other way around. i.e each zip code has an array that references an industry instead of each industry referencing a zip code. Not sure which one is more efficient or if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve my issue

```
    let queue = []
    let industries = await Industry.find({})
    let zips = await Zip.find({})
    zips.map(zip => {
        industries.map(industry => {
            if(zip.industries_indexed.length > 0){
                zip.industries_indexed.map(index =>{
                    if(!(industry._id.equals(index.industry))){
                        queue.push({
                            zip_ref: zip,
                            industry_ref: industry
                        })
                    }
                })
            }else{
                queue.push({
                    zip_ref: zip,
                    industry_ref: industry
                })
            }

        })
    })
    return queue;
```